# Title of page not showing in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have this controller in CodeIgniter that loads a header view and another view:

```
class Add_user extends CI_Controller{
function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();

    }
public function index(){
    $this->load->view('header_view');
    $this->load->view('add_user_view');
}
```

So,  this page:
 `http://localhost/my-project/index.php/add_user` is supposed to have the title of `add_user_view` , but it doesn't and I don't understand why.

Comment: That's the order I have

Comment: change the order: first: add_user_view, sorry

Comment: I fixed it by passing data to the header view, like the answer of @wolfgang suggested

Answer (score 0):

This is the proper way to done that thing:

```
class Add_user extends CI_Controller {

            // MVC config
            var $CONTROLLER = 'contoller name';
            var $MODEL = 'model name';
            var $TITLE = 'page title name';
            var $LIST_PAGE_NAME = 'view page name';

            function Add_user() {
                parent::__construct();
                $this->load->model($this->MODEL, 'model');
            }

            public function index(){
              $this->load->view('header_view');
              $this->load->view('add_user_view');
            }
       }
```

Now in this controller, model or view. If you have to use above global varaible code like this.

```
<?php echo $this->TITLE; ?>
```